# How to select an non mapped field in NHibernate?

Tags: c#, t-sql, nhibernate

I Have a named query that retrieves a list of objects of class "Expediente". I need to add a computed field (confirmado) to this objects, but I can't figure out how to map this field for this particular query. I've tried in the mapping file using **insert="false" update="false"** but then every single query needs the field.
Can you help me?

```
<sql-query name="BuscarExpedientes">
<return alias="e" class="GestionDPV.Core.Expediente, GestionDPV.Core"/>
<return-join alias="cab" property="e.Agregados"/>
<![CDATA[
  SELECT e.*,
  CASE
    WHEN p.id IS NULL THEN p.confirmado
    ELSE 1
  END AS confirmado
  FROM Expedientes e
  LEFT JOIN Expedientes cab ON cab.id = e.idCabecera
  LEFT JOIN Pases p ON p.idExpediente = e.id AND p.fechaGeneracion = (SELECT MAX(fechaGeneracion) FROM Pases WHERE idExpediente = e.id)
]]>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<return-scalar>`. See the [documentation](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#querysql-namedqueries).

Btw, if you expect a `<return-join>`, you have to select it's columns too.

Comment: I've tried this method but with return-scalar, i can't map this scalar value as a property in the class. That is my problem, return the entire class plus this extra field